# Counter not displaying when refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

So in this code when I like/dislike a message, the counter (next to it) increases by 1 and the image changes. However, when I refresh the site, the image stays, but the counter doesn't. The counter completely disappears.

I want the counter to display next to the like/dislike button when refreshing the site and not disappear. Because of this, I am 99% sure that this is a local storage problem.

Another thing is that when I refresh the site, the counters are displayed for a split second before disappearing.

```
e<body>
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Message Board</h2>

    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="reply_to" id="reply_to">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" required></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    if (!empty($messages)) {
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $name = $message['name'];
            $messageText = $message['message'];
            $repliedName = $message['repliedName'];
            $repliedText = $message['repliedText'];
            $likeCount = $message['likeCount'];
            $dislikeCount = $message['dislikeCount'];
            $messageId = $message['id'];

            echo "<div class='message'>";
            echo "<strong>$name:</strong> $messageText";

            if (!empty($repliedName) && !empty($repliedText)) {
                echo "<div class='reply'>";
                echo "<strong>Reply to $repliedName:</strong> $repliedText";
                echo "</div>";
            }

            echo "<div class='reply-container'>";
            echo "<button id='likeBtn$messageId' onclick='likeMessage($messageId)'>";
            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/kgSLXwP/image-2023-08-09-221334071.png' alt='Like' class='button-icon thumbs-up-image'>";
            echo "<span id='likeCount$messageId' data-count='$likeCount'>$likeCount</span></button>";

            echo "<button id='dislikeBtn$messageId' onclick='dislikeMessage($messageId)'>";
            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/MN55Sw1/OIP-6.png' alt='Dislike' class='button-icon thumbs-down-image'>";
            echo "<span id='dislikeCount$messageId' data-count='$dislikeCount'>$dislikeCount</span></button>";

            echo "<button class='reply-btn' onclick=\"setReplyTo($messageId)\">Reply</button>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    function setReplyTo(messageId) {
        document.getElementById('reply_to').value = messageId;
    }
</script>
<script>
function likeMessage(messageId) {
    // Check if the message is already liked or disliked
    if (localStorage.getItem(`liked_${messageId}`) === '1') {
      console.log('Message is already liked.');
      return;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem(`disliked_${messageId}`) === '1') {
      console.log('Message is already disliked.');
      return;
    }

    // Send an AJAX request to update the like count in the database
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'update_likes.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (response.success) {
          const likeBtn = document.getElementById(`likeBtn${messageId}`);
          likeBtn.innerHTML = `<img src='https://i.ibb.co/wpmSdDC/thumbsup-green.png' alt='Like' class='button-icon thumbs-up-image'> (${response.likeCount})`;
          likeBtn.disabled = true;

          // Store the liked message in local storage
          localStorage.setItem(`liked_${messageId}`, '1');
          localStorage.removeItem(`disliked_${messageId}`); // Remove from disliked messages

          // Update the like count display
          const likeCountSpan = document.getElementById(`likeCount${messageId}`);
          if (likeCountSpan) {
            likeCountSpan.textContent = response.likeCount;
          }
        } else {
          console.error(response.message);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send(`messageId=${messageId}&action=like`);
  }

  function dislikeMessage(messageId) {
    // Check if the message is already liked or disliked
    if (localStorage.getItem(`liked_${messageId}`) === '1') {
      console.log('Message is already liked.');
      return;
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem(`disliked_${messageId}`) === '1') {
      console.log('Message is already disliked.');
      return;
    }

    // Send an AJAX request to update the dislike count in the database
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'update_likes.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (response.success) {
          const dislikeBtn = document.getElementById(`dislikeBtn${messageId}`);
          dislikeBtn.innerHTML = `<img src='https://i.ibb.co/YLjV9ZW/thumbsdown-red.png' alt='Dislike' class='button-icon thumbs-down-image'> (${response.dislikeCount})`;
          dislikeBtn.disabled = true;

          // Store the disliked message in local storage
          localStorage.setItem(`disliked_${messageId}`, '1');
          localStorage.removeItem(`liked_${messageId}`); // Remove from liked messages

          // Update the dislike count display
          const dislikeCountSpan = document.getElementById(`dislikeCount${messageId}`);
          if (dislikeCountSpan) {
            dislikeCountSpan.textContent = response.dislikeCount;
          }
        } else {
          console.error(response.message);
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send(`messageId=${messageId}&action=dislike`);
  }

  // Restore the button states, and images, on page load
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const likedMessages = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function (key) {
    return key.startsWith('liked_');
  });
  likedMessages.forEach(function (key) {
    const messageId = key.replace('liked_', '');
    const likeBtn = document.getElementById(`likeBtn${messageId}`);
    if (likeBtn) {
      likeBtn.innerHTML = `<img src='https://i.ibb.co/wpmSdDC/thumbsup.png' alt='Like' class='button-icon thumbs-up-image'>`;
      likeBtn.disabled = true;
    }
  });

  const dislikedMessages = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function (key) {
    return key.startsWith('disliked_');
  });
  dislikedMessages.forEach(function (key) {
    const messageId = key.replace('disliked_', '');
    const dislikeBtn = document.getElementById(`dislikeBtn${messageId}`);
    if (dislikeBtn) {
      dislikeBtn.innerHTML = `<img src='https://i.ibb.co/YLjV9ZW/disliked.png' alt='Dislike' class='button-icon thumbs-down-image'>`;
      dislikeBtn.disabled = true;
    }
  });

  // Update the counter displays
  const likeCountSpans = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="likeCount"]');
  likeCountSpans.forEach(function (likeCountSpan) {
    const messageId = likeCountSpan.id.replace('likeCount', '');
    const likeCount = likeCountSpan.dataset.count;
    const storedLikeCount = localStorage.getItem(`likeCount_${messageId}`);
    if (storedLikeCount) {
      likeCountSpan.textContent = storedLikeCount;
    } else {
      likeCountSpan.textContent = likeCount;
    }
  });

  const dislikeCountSpans = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="dislikeCount"]');
  dislikeCountSpans.forEach(function (dislikeCountSpan) {
    const messageId = dislikeCountSpan.id.replace('dislikeCount', '');
    const dislikeCount = dislikeCountSpan.dataset.count;
    const storedDislikeCount = localStorage.getItem(`dislikeCount_${messageId}`);
    if (storedDislikeCount) {
      dislikeCountSpan.textContent = storedDislikeCount;
    } else {
      dislikeCountSpan.textContent = dislikeCount;
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is what's causing the issue, primarily the script at the end.

I tried to fix it and I was expecting the counter to stay after reloading the site but it doesn't.

Comment: You are not storing anything for the counter in localStorage? I can only see that you store `liked_message${messageId}` and `disliked_message${messageId}` nothing else?

Comment: Sorry that was an old code. I think the copy command didnt work.  I updated the code with the one i have now

Comment: Also, you do not have to add all code you have like css and stuff like that. Just add the parts that is relevant to the actual question. The database part is not relevant as well (I guess) since you are fetching the data from local storage?

Comment: I see ```localStorage.getItem(`dislikeCount_${messageId}`);``` but there's no code that ever sets this.